# Is there an equivalent of the Mac OS X "say" command in Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, command-line

Is there an equivalent to the Mac's terminal command "say" in Ubuntu 9.10?

Comment: As an aside: a nice list of English sentences in which Mac OS X understands the context quite well, like "My name is Dr. Smith and I live on Smith Dr.", "The soldier decided to desert his dessert in the desert", "The guard will permit you to pass if you show a valid permit" and "It is much rainier on the slopes of Mt. Rainier" at http://www.macosxhints.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=107211

Answer (score 86, accepted):

espeak should be installed by default as text-to-speech engine on Linux.

You should be able to get it to speak from command-line by doing something like this:

```
echo "Text to speak"|espeak
```

You can also start espeak by just entering `espeak` itself, and then enter each line of text you want spoken followed by enter.

Other TTS engines for Linux you could look at:

- http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/
- http://epos.ure.cas.cz/

Espeak is available at (but should be installed by default!):

- http://espeak.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you wanted this to directly replace the say command you could use a function:

function say() { echo "@" | espeak ; }

Comment: on Linux Mint is NOT installed by default ;)

Comment: Espeak is not installed by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: There's no need for echoing and piping. You can simply do `espeak "how, now, brown, cow"`

Answer (score 31):

```
alias say='echo "$1" | espeak -s 120 2>/dev/null'
```

Then you can use:

```
say 'How are you doing?'
```

Explanation:

```
-s 120 #to make it slower than default
2>/dev/null #to eliminate error masseges on the console
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when i source .bashrc from a script

Comment: By default, Bash does not import aliases from sourced files when the shell is not interactive, like in a shell script. https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script

Comment: By default, Bash does not import aliases from sourced files when the shell is not interactive, like in a shell script. https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of speech synthesizers available to install in karmic, most of the ones I've tried have a console version.

Search for "Speech" in synaptic to get the full list. The `espeak` package works like `say`.

Answer (score 4):

install **speech-dispatcher** along with a synthesizer (flite, festival, etc) then

```
alias say='echo "$1" | spd-say -p -25 -e'
```

that will use whatever synthesizer you have configured.

The -p -25 is setting the pitch lower... change as desired.  -e uses stdin

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper knock off, you can apt install [gnustep-gui-runtime](https://gnustep.github.io). It's an knockoff of Apple's Cocoa written in Objective C.